# WithProps vs withHandlers

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I've been looking at react recompose library and trying to grasp difference here, result is the same, tried to read docs, but got even more confused, why there is two ways to do same thing ?

```
const enhance = compose(
  withState('counter', 'setCounter', 0),
  withHandlers({
    increment: props => () => props.setCounter(n => n + 1),
    decrement: props => () => props.setCounter(n => n - 1)
  })
)

const enhance = compose(
  withState('counter', 'setCounter', 0),
  withProps(({ setCounter }) => ({
    increment: () => setCounter(n => n + 1),
    decrement: () => setCounter(n => n - 1)
  }))
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's mostly performance related, as `withHandlers` doesn't create a new function every render. From a [related Github issue](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/issues/315#issuecomment-280981617):

> `withProps` will create new functions every time when it get updated; on
>   the other hand, `withHandlers` won't create new functions.
>
> `withHandlers` is useful when you want to pass these functions to other
>   components which `shouldComponents` are implemented by comparing props
>   shallowly (like how `recompose/pure` do).

Answer (score 8):

Additionally to Fabian Schultz' answer, note that `withProps` can be used to add any type of prop, while `withHandlers` can only add functions.

So when you add functions, use `withHandlers` when possible, for performance. When you add anything else, use `withProps` (or `mapProps` if you want to remove all other props).